# How to use jQuery to fade out main div and fade in content from corresponding clicked thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A little new with jQuery...I'm setting up a portfolio page. I have a main div that displays an image and description of a project, then a list of thumbnail texts (brief titles) for all projects. This is what I'm trying to do:

When a specific thumbnail text is clicked, the main div fades out the currently visible project and fades in the project corresponding to the thumbnail. What's the best way to use href to load target content into the main display?

Can't seem to find a plugin that lets me do this easily. Been trying to use a bit of javascript from http://perishablepress.com/slide-fade-content.

```
<!--MAIN DISPLAY-->
<div id="main">
<div id="projectA">
<img src="projectA-image.png" />
<div id="projectA">Description of Project A...</div>
</div>

<!--THUMBNAILS-->
<div class="thumb">
<a href="#projectA" class="thumb-text">PROJECT A</a>
</div>

<div class="thumb">
<a href="#projectB" class="thumb-text">PROJECT B</a>
</div>
```

Here's as far as I've gotten with javascript:

```
 $('div.thumb-text').click(function () {    
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('div#piece-content').fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $('div#piece-content').load('portfolio.html#' +href);

        });
      });
```

Comment: You load data into `div#piece-content` but you do not show the element - does adding `$('div#piece-content').show()` perhaps help?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues here.  First, your selector is wrong.  `div.thumb-text` will select all `div`s with a class of `thumb-text`.  You have none of those.  This should be either `div .thumb-text` to find all elements within a `div` with the class of `thumb-text` or `a.thumb-text` to get all `a` tags with the class of `thumb-text`.

2nd, `$('div#piece-content').load('portfolio.html#' +href);` you will end up with two `#`s in this case since `href` already has one.  And I'm not sure what your intention is here but `#` is not used to pass things to the backend, you may be intending to use `?`, not entirely sure what you were going for here.

And finally, you never fade the element back in.  So in your `.load` you need a callback:

```
$('div#piece-content').load('portfolio.html#' +href, function(){
   $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things: you cannot do `portfolio.html#` (that is a hashtag) but you can do regular jQuery `selectors` inside the `load`. If you want to get the `div` with `id` of `photos` then use `load('portfolio.html #photos')` That is not a hash tag, that is a selector, just to make things clear.

Another thing: a lot of your `HTML` does not match your jQuery selectors at all. For example, you reference `div#piece-content` but I don't see that in your `DOM`. Same with `div.thumb-text`, it looks like you want `$('div.thumb').children('a.thumb-text')` instead.

Thirdly: assuming `div.piece-content` is the main div you were talking about, simply calling a `fadeOut` from what I understand, will not work. It will simply set its opacity to 0 and then it will load content into it. You should do your `fadeOut()`, then load the content *then* call `fadeIn()`

```
$('div.thumb-text').click(function() {    
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('div#piece-content').fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $(this).load('portfolio.html #' +href', {}, function() {
                $(this).fadeIn();
            });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would definitely dig deeper in Google for existing plugins, especially if you are a beginner with jQuery.

Maybe the [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) could be something?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, here's what I ended up with in javascript:

```
var activeDiv=$('#project-A'); //set activeDiv to the first piece you want to show 

              $('a.thumb-text').click(function () {     

                var href = $(this).attr('href'); //grabs the href from <a class="thumb-text">


                    activeDiv.fadeOut("fast", function() { //fades out the currently showing piece
                        $(href).fadeIn("slow");
                        activeDiv = $(href); //set the active piece to what was clicked on

                    });

              });
```